# Add a toolbar to a tableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, toolbar

I'm using the XCode 4.3 "Master/Detail" template for the iPhone.  At the ROOT level, this is a UIToolbarController.  I want navigation and toolbars.  The navigation is easy--the template already uses the self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem (and right) to add buttons, but I can't find a way to add *useful* toolbar items.  I can add a toolbar (see below), but this gets added to the scroll view of the tableview, so scrolls up and down with the table contents--not very useful.  The tableView.view has no superview which is where you'd think a tool bar should go. It has no window either! (all these properties are null).

That top navbar must belong to some view which is not scrolled, but what?!!  Setting the toolbarHidden property of self.navigationController has no effect (setting the navigationBarHidden to YES does not hide the nav bar either).

Obviously something I don't understand here...

```
// this toolbar scrolls with the tableview contents!
INavigationController *nvc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self];
nvc.toolbarHidden = NO;
[self.view addSubview:nvc.view];
```

Comment: After 4 weeks (on and off) I found the answer an hour after posting. I was adding the toolbar stuff in *viewDidLoad* (where the template added the left and right navigation buttons).  Looks like there is no navigationConreoller at this time.  Adding the custom buttons to the tableViewController.toolbarItems array and setting toolBarHidden to NO in *viewWillAppear* (when we have a navigationController) fixes the problem!  Didn't see this documented anywhere...

Answer (score 1):

Just highlight the navigation controller and then look at the attributes. check "Shows Toolbar" to unhide the toolbar that is already there.